# How do I get Heroku to run my node app that's in a subfolder?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a node app where the entry point is here

```
/backend/src/index.js
```

Locally, if I try to run `node ./backend/src/index.js` from the project root I get lots of pathing errors, but if I `cd` into the `backend` folder and run `./src/index.js` my node app runs. I assume this is all due to the use of relative paths through the node app.

How can I deploy this app to heroku and have it run correctly? I'm currently getting 503 errors like this

```
2017-07-31T03:02:17.759410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=[redacted] ... dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Is there some way to tell heroku to `cd` into the `backend` folder before executing the start script? Can I do this with a `Procfile`?

Comment: Not answer its a work around: How about creating a symlink to your index.js use the one from root in your Procfile.  You can create symlink with this command ln -s ./backend/src/index.js index.js

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Heroku's standard NodeJS buildpack, I can think of one way to get you started.

This buildpack actually searches for `package.json` in your root path (so that's a requirement). In `package.json`, you can specify a start script for your app, like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cd backend/src && node index.js"
}
```

This should direct Heroku to `cd` into your directory and then start the server from there. You can refer to the related documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process).

Comment: Thanks @31piy, I didn't even think to use `cd` in the script...massive oversight on my part, LOL. I'll give that a go tonight!

Comment: Didn't work, but that may have been an issue my app. I ended up restructuring and am able to run it in Heroku now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Heroku requires a `package.json` and a lockfile in the root of the repository or they will fail the deploy.

However you can set up a `package.json` in the root of the repo which installs dependencies for the subdirectories and runs their related commands.

Using yarn for example (you can something similar with npm), you could put an empty `yarn.lock` in the root and a `package.json` like:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "yarn --cwd <subdirectory> --production=false install",
    "build": "yarn --cwd <subdirectory> serve"
  }
}
```

The `--production=false` is optional, but [ensures that devDependencies will be installed](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/), which otherwise wouldn't happen since `NODE_ENV` is set to `production` in Heroku's environment.

Heroku's buildpack installs devDependencies by default and then prunes them later, so if you need any of them to build your project as part of deploying it you will need that part.